# Unity2D pong's ball bouncing (not using unity's physics)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pong

I am creating Pong in Unity2D.
I got stuck on the bounce part for the ball. I would normally know how to do it, except this time my exercise is to re-create pong without using Unity's physics.

I managed to make it bounce, somehow, but it goes on bouncing in the same 2 spots forever,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo7JT.png).

My code is to make it bounce like in the photo is:

```
if (transform.position.y - (ball.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
            <= botBorder.gameObject.transform.position.y + botBorder.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }
        else if (transform.position.y + (ball.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
            >= topBorder.gameObject.transform.position.y - topBorder.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }
```

The idea was to change its speed to make it go in the opposite direction.
Now I really do not know how to make it bounce properly.
I tried changing the X and Y, but nothing changes. Also tried to modify the forward, but I suppose I didn't do it in the correct way.

I know what I'm missing is probably how to resolve a basic trigonometry problem, but I have spent days on this and really do not know what to do.

Complete code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("ball speed")]
    public float speed;

    [Tooltip("X random calculated in the Start to randomize the initial direction")]
    private float randomX;
    [Tooltip("Y random calculated in the Start to randomize the initial direction")]
    private float randomY;

    //References to know the borders positions for the bounces, and of the ball to understand where it is
    public SpriteRenderer topBorder;
    public SpriteRenderer botBorder;
    public SpriteRenderer ball;

    void Start()
    {
        //First trajectory of the ball. Randomized
        randomX = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        randomY = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(speed * randomX * Time.deltaTime, 
                                          speed * randomY * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        CheckBorders();
    }

    void CheckBorders()
    {
        if (transform.position.y - (ball.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
            <= botBorder.gameObject.transform.position.y + botBorder.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }
        else if (transform.position.y + (ball.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
            >= topBorder.gameObject.transform.position.y - topBorder.gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This post should help you to correct the ball bouncing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector

Comment: Use your high school physics.  When you bound a ball off of a surface what angle to it use?  It is 180 degrees from original angle.  You just change the vector direction to be -1 times the current direction (go in reverse) and not the angle.  You need to change angle to 180 - angle.

Comment: @atalantus Thanks a lot. I will check it out right now to understand the problem.

Comment: @jdweng I understand what you are saying, and that is why i put the speed in negative if positive, and positive if negative. What I do not know is how to access the angle without having a reference to the rigidbody. I tried already going for another Vector and changing the sign depending on the outcome of the if's condition, but nothing happened.

Comment: You always need a DATUM which is a reference point that describes a 3-D axis (or 2-D).  The axis has a zero degree direction which is the direction of x-axis which in you case is the bottom wall toward the right.  You also have a top wall that is parallel to the bottom wall.  To if you ball is originally going 135 degrees and hits the top wall what is new angle?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear about your math level, in short, if the ball hits any border, you need reverse `randomY` not `speed`.

```
randomY *= -1;
```

If the ball hits any bat, then you need reverse `randomX`.

```
randomX *= -1;
```

---

In physics moving a ball needs a vector, for better readability, I suggest to replace `speed randomX randomY` with `Vector2 velocity`. The code now may look like:

```
void Start()
{
    //First trajectory of the ball. Randomized
    velocity.x = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
    velocity.y = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

 void Update()
{
    transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    CheckBorders();
}

void CheckBorders()
{
   if(... ball hits border ...)
       velocity.y *= -1;
   else if(... ball hits bat ...)
       velocity.x *= -1;
}
```

Comment: My math level is very bad, to be honest.

So, to understand: I need to flip the Y because the borders are both located on the Y axes, whilst the bats are located in the X axes? 
Am I understanding it correctly?

The speed *= -1 was to understand if the logic I had was correct, which somehow was correct and yet was incorrect.

Thank you very much for the answer.